# Регулярное выражение: не более 2 пробелов между словами

Tags: javascript, html, регулярные-выражения

Есть простой RegExp `[а-яёА-ЯЁ]{0,1}[\sа-яёА-ЯЁ.\-]{1,}`, который первым символом принимает только буквы, а дальше любые символы и буквы.

Как запретить ввод 2 подряд идущих пробелов между словами?

Comment: Дальше не "любые символы и буквы" и почему не `?` и `+`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте

```
 /^[а-яёА-ЯЁ]+(?:\s[а-яёА-ЯЁ.-]+)*$/
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/s6lIAT/2)

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `[а-яёА-ЯЁ]+` - 1 и более русских букв
- `(?:\s[а-яёА-ЯЁ.-]+)*` - 0 и более повторов

  - `\s` - 1 пробельный символ
  - `[а-яёА-ЯЁ.-]+` - 1 и более русских букв, точек или дефисов
- `$` - конец строки

Если пробелы, точки и дефисы не могут следовать друг за другом, используйте

```
/^[а-яёА-ЯЁ]+(?:[\s.-][а-яёА-ЯЁ]+)*$/
```

Answer (score 2):

```
input { box-sizing: border-box; width: 60%; border: 1px double; outline: none; }
:valid { border-color: orange; }
:invalid { border-color: red; }
<input pattern="^((?!\s{2}).)*$" autofocus>
```